# Which has more sensitivity: a 10 volt per unit length or 30 volt per unit length potentiometer?

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, voltage

according to me sensitivity of potentiometer should be like: with less increase in length , i am getting more volt that is 20 volt/l should be more sensitive than 10 volt/l because < i am getting more volts in less length, hence more sensitive potentiometer?

Answer (score 0):

If by sensitivity, you mean the deviation of emf per unit length then you are absolutely correct. The potentiometer wire which drops greater voltage will be more sensitive. Also, I would like to add that it would be most sensitive at the midpoint of the resistive wire as compared to the ends.